# Facebook Send Button displays wrong href URI & returns error

Tags: facebook-like

I have installed Facebook Like/Send buttons on 4 websites in the past year (with asynchronous javascript) but I have noticed that the Send button no longer works (although it did when tested on install).

For example #1: http://www.libbiking.com/

On the relevant page I added:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Libbi King" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.libbiking.com/" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.libbiking.com/mygallery/site/img/www_libbiking_com_facebook_01.gif" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Libbi King" />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="618598922" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="251724341605334" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Illustrator &amp; Set Designer in London | libbi@libbiking.com | tel: 07706 553 288" />
```

and

```
        <div id="fb-root"></div>        
        <script type="text/javascript">
          window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({
              appId      : '251724341605334', // App ID
              channelUrl : '//www.libbiking.com/mygallery/site/libbiking/fb_channel.php', // Channel File
              status     : true, // check login status
              cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
              xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
            });

            // Additional initialization code here
          };

          // Load the SDK Asynchronously
          (function(d){
             var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
             if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
             js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
             js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
             ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
           }(document));
        </script>

    <fb:like href="http://www.libbiking.com/" send="true" layout="button_count" width="180" show_faces="false" font="segoe ui"></fb:like>
```

with the fb_channel.php:

```
<?php
$cache_expire = 60*60*24*365;
header("Pragma: public");
header("Cache-Control: max-age=".$cache_expire);
header('Expires: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time()+$cache_expire) . ' GMT');
?>
<script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
```

Curiously, it now displays a secure https URI to a Facebook page (not the website). When sent an error message is returned:

'We encountered the following error when sending your message: The page at https://www.facebook.com/pages/Libbi-King/355311097871934 could not be reached because the server returned status code 200'

I have parsed the page through the Facebook Linter/Debugger & the OG seems fine with a Response Code 200. I am unsure why this is causing an error as It is my understanding that Response Code 200 is a successful page retrieval. If I replace the button href with an incorrect URI the send button actually works!

I have noticed that when registering the App, the type description has recently changed from 'Website' to 'Website with Facebook Login'. I do not know if this may cause the issue...

Comment: Any news on this?  I'm having the exact same problem.

Comment: I made a similar posting to Facebook Bugs which has been assessed as low priority. Similar postings made this year remain unresolved. I have abandoned the Send button as Facebook are failing to support it...   https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/398645746849154?browse=search_4ffc5d8ca6f079158297107